# Formula to copy value from 1 column but if blank take value from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for help with a formula -
If a cell has a value return it if not look at different cell and return that value.
For example I want R4 to return the value in Q4 but if Q4 is blank I want it to show the P4 value

[image: Column compare]

Comment: Explore Excel help for functions like ISBLANK & IF

Comment: It's great you want to get the Value of R4 in Q4 using a Formula but expecting P4 value in Q4 if is BLANK,,,? What exactly you are suppose to do!! May be you need is like,, Get the Value from R4 in Q4 but if R4 is BLANK get value from P4,, write,,!

Comment: Comments like these really don't help.

Comment: If is the situation you can use this Formula, in Q4 =IF(ISBLANK(R4),P4,R4). Or you specify your exact need.

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following formula in cell R4:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Q4);P4;Q4)
```

It may be that you have to substitute the `;` for a `,` depending on your regional settings.

Explaination:

=IF(equation;if true; if false)
If the equation is met, the part of if true is executed. If the equation is not met, the part of if false is executed.

=ISBLANK(cell) Returns true if the data in the reference cell is empty. Do note, if the cell contains a space, it is not marked as blank. The same applies if the cell has the value 0 or a formula, even if that formula returns "".

Comment: Nice answer. Chip must be across the pond somewhere.  :-)  So OP may need to separate the parameters with commas instead of  semicolons.  Also, ISBLANK() will return False if the cell contains a formula, even if the result of the formula makes the cell appear blank.  It's better to think of the formula as ISEMPTY().

Comment: @Bandersnatch thanks for the comment. I've edited the post. As for the , vs ;... as far as I know ; should always work, where , may work depending on the locale.

Comment: ; does not always work, it, like “,” depend on what is set in the system. So, best advice is check what is being used ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple columns and you need last nonblank column value then you can use FILTER AND KEEP formula like below.

`=TAKE(FILTER(A2:E2,A2:E2<>""),,-1)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).